# Access current position in svg using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I want to access current position that defined in variables. After that I want to make the element of that position was colored automatically when I load the page. The problem is I don't know how to access that defined position and append the color to html when its load.
I've try it in this, but it gets nothing colored when I load the page. Maybe my code was wrong and can anyone help?

https://jsfiddle.net/ax47kvu5/1/

```
var gigi = "P15";//id of g
var posisi = "C";//id of polygon
var kondisi = "amf";
if(kondisi=="amf"){
var group = $('polygon').parentNode().attr(gigi);
group.attr(posisi).css({fill: "#333333"});
$('polygon').html('XX');
}
```

Comment: The file is invalid as there are multiple elements with the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/9n9jack8/ - In your example you didn't load jQuery, this is the first issue.`$("#P15").find("#C").css({fill: "#333333"});`

Comment: The other issue is that there are multiple elements with the same id so the file is invalid.

Comment: @HpetruAlin how to replace $("#P15").find("#C") with defined variable ?

Comment: now depends on what do you need you can do something like `var parent="P15"; var chid = "C"; var color='red'; $("#"+parent).find("#"+chid).css({fill:color});`
https://jsfiddle.net/9n9jack8/